# How to use Hook API style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am learning 'how to style material ui components'. In the tutorial it gives you this Hook Api code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

**As far as I understand, I have a new button having this style props. My question is how I can use this new button inside my render?**

```
class CreateUserPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // How to use it???
        );    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how I can use this new button inside my render?

You created a component that is named `Hook`. (You should change it to `Button` or `StyledButton`, something like that.

```
export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

To use it in `CreateUserPage`, you just import it and render it like a normal React Component.

```
import Hook from '../place/here/your/component/is'

class CreateUserPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <Hook />
        );    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I also export multiple Hook functions like that?

Comment: @ErayTuncer Yes. It's not called `Hook functions`, but `Functional Components`, wich is also React Component. The hook function would be `useStyles`, wich can only be used in `Functional Components` and don't work with `Class Components`.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs to be saved in a **dedicated javascript file** (eg. `NewButton.js`)  which you will now be able to **import from** other components.

```
import NewButton from './NewButton'

<NewButton>Hi</NewButton>
```

You will need to adapt your hook to **propagate it's content**:

```
export default function Hook({children}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>{children}</Button>;
}
```